# Regex to remove excess backslashes in python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I've the following text in a list:

text='More Fulham open to offers for Stefan Johansen, Jean Michael Seri and Maxime Le Marchand QPR are keen on Fulham\'s Stefan Johansen who was not included in Scott Parker\'s Premier League squad this season; Galatasaray want Jean Michael Seri back on loan while Maxime Le Marchand is attracting interest from former club Nice Fill 2 Copy 11 Wednesday 20 January 2021 16:51, UK Image: Queens Park Rangers are interested in signing Stefan Johansen\\nFulham are listening to offers for Stefan Johansen, Maxime Le Marchand and Jean Michael Seri during the January transfer window.\\nQueens Park Rangers are interested in signing Fulham midfielder Johansen. The Norwegian international was not included in Scott Parker\'s Premier League squad for the first half of this season.\\nJohansen, 30, has made 142 appearances for the club since arriving from Celtic in 2016, he is under contract at Craven Cottage until 2022. Parker: I don\'t owe Mourinho an apology\\nThe midfielder spent the second half of the 2018/19 campaign on loan at West Brom but returned ahead of the following season and played 33 times in the Championship as Fulham won promotion back to the Premier League via the play-offs. Image: Jean Michael Seri spent last season on loan at Galatasaray\\nTalks continue between Fulham and Galatasaray over the possibility of a loan deal for midfielder Jean Michael Seri. Trending Latest News\\nA move would see the 29-year-old central midfielder join the Turkish club on loan for a second time, with Seri having played 37 times for the Super Lig side while he was there last season.\\nSeri\'s contract expires in the summer of 2022, he has the option to extend the deal by a further year. Also See: Image: Maxime Le Marchand played 12 times for Fulham last season but has made just two appearances under Scott Parker so far this term\\nMeanwhile, Ligue 1 club Nice want defender Maxime Le Marchand to return to the Allianz Riviera.\\nFulham signed Le Marchand from the French side in July 2018 and the centre-back has featured just twice in the top flight so far this season.\\nLe Marchand also has a year and a half remaining on his current contract at Fulham.\\nFulham, who are 18th and four points from safety in the Premier League, play Manchester United (January 20), Burnley in the FA Cup (January 24), Brighton (January 27), and West Brom (January 30) before the end of the month.\\nFollow the January transfer window with Sky Sports\\nThe winter transfer window is open until Monday, February 1 at 11pm.\\nFollow all the news and analysis on Sky Sports News and across Sky Sports \' digital platforms, including our dedicated Transfer Centre blog'

and using the following regex with expecting to remove \:

```
re.sub(r'\\\\\'',"\\'",text))
```

however, output is cleaning the extra \

for example, the text has {don\\'t} and with following regex I intended to convert it to don't

Comment: Please edit your question to make the example smaller and make it display as code using 3 backticks ` at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use replace method. No need to use regex if you just wanna remove '\'.'
Obviously, you need to remove '\n', '\t', etc, and then you can use this to remove extra '\'

```
text = text.replace('\\','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Very weirdly I was just looking this up 15 minutes ago. I had a few attempts with your text and found something that worked.

First, using `repr(text)` will show the actual backslashes being used. Replacing `\\\\` with `\\` at this point will result in the correct string as if it was written in Python. It's basically the equivalent of `'"' + text + '"'`, but a bit safer in terms of potentially unescaped speech marks.

From here, `eval` will actually process it as a string.

```
result = eval(repr(text).replace('\\\\', '\\'))
```

When you then print the result, this is what you get:

```
More Fulham open to offers for Stefan Johansen, Jean Michael Seri and Maxime Le Marchand QPR are keen on Fulham's Stefan Johansen who was not included in Scott Parker's Premier League squad this season; Galatasaray want Jean Michael Seri back on loan while Maxime Le Marchand is attracting interest from former club Nice Fill 2 Copy 11 Wednesday 20 January 2021 16:51, UK Image: Queens Park Rangers are interested in signing Stefan Johansen
Fulham are listening to offers for Stefan Johansen, Maxime Le Marchand and Jean Michael Seri during the January transfer window.
Queens Park Rangers are interested in signing Fulham midfielder Johansen. The Norwegian international was not included in Scott Parker's Premier League squad for the first half of this season.
Johansen, 30, has made 142 appearances for the club since arriving from Celtic in 2016, he is under contract at Craven Cottage until 2022. Parker: I don't owe Mourinho an apology
The midfielder spent the second half of the 2018/19 campaign on loan at West Brom but returned ahead of the following season and played 33 times in the Championship as Fulham won promotion back to the Premier League via the play-offs. Image: Jean Michael Seri spent last season on loan at Galatasaray
Talks continue between Fulham and Galatasaray over the possibility of a loan deal for midfielder Jean Michael Seri. Trending Latest News
A move would see the 29-year-old central midfielder join the Turkish club on loan for a second time, with Seri having played 37 times for the Super Lig side while he was there last season.
Seri's contract expires in the summer of 2022, he has the option to extend the deal by a further year. Also See: Image: Maxime Le Marchand played 12 times for Fulham last season but has made just two appearances under Scott Parker so far this term
Meanwhile, Ligue 1 club Nice want defender Maxime Le Marchand to return to the Allianz Riviera.
Fulham signed Le Marchand from the French side in July 2018 and the centre-back has featured just twice in the top flight so far this season.
Le Marchand also has a year and a half remaining on his current contract at Fulham.
Fulham, who are 18th and four points from safety in the Premier League, play Manchester United (January 20), Burnley in the FA Cup (January 24), Brighton (January 27), and West Brom (January 30) before the end of the month.
Follow the January transfer window with Sky Sports
The winter transfer window is open until Monday, February 1 at 11pm.
Follow all the news and analysis on Sky Sports News and across Sky Sports ' digital platforms, including our dedicated Transfer Centre blog
```